# How to close site navbar when onclick outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created site navbar but don't know how to close this when user click outside. I tried "focus" on hamburger button, but it's not great way. Actually I used "toggleClass" in javascript and my navbar open/close during clicking. I have no idea how to do this.

> HTML

```
<button id="hamburger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </button>

        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" >Main </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> More </a></li>
        </ul>
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
    hamburger.addEventListener('click',function(){
       menu.classList.toggle('open');
      });
```

> CSS

```
      .menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: fixed;
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(26, 23, 36, 0.96);
        border-right: 1px solid #8383a2;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: 0.3s transform linear;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
        .open {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One solution would be adding an overlay under your menu and close
   menu on click event of this overlay.
2. Another one is checking in click event of whole document if menu is
   opened and something outside of it was clicked.
3. Using focusout or blur event is yet another solution, but it needs to
   be remembered that it requires tabindex attribute for such HTML
   elements as div or ul.

Below you may find working example of the second approach.

```js
hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
menu = document.getElementById('menu');
hamburger.addEventListener('click',function(event){
       menu.classList.toggle('open');
      });
      
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(menu.classList.contains('open') && !event.target.isEqualNode(hamburger) && !event.target.isEqualNode(menu) && !menu.contains(event.target)) {
      menu.classList.remove('open');
  }
});
```

```css
   .menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: fixed;
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(26, 23, 36, 0.96);
        border-right: 1px solid #8383a2;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: 0.3s transform linear;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
        .open {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
```

```html
<button id="hamburger">
            I am hamburger
        </button>

        <ul class="menu" id = "menu" >
            <li><a href="#" >Main </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> More </a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) or [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event handlers on your menu element.

For example:

```
menu.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
    // close the menu  
});
```

Following @matvs's comment: you might also need to add the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute to your menu element, in order for its focusout/blur event to be triggered. For example:

```
<ul class="menu" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that without tabindex attribute focus and consequently focusout or blur event won't be fired for HTML elements such as div or ul.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a click listener, for example, I have 2 sections `<section id="content">...</section>` and `<section id="navbar">...</section>`, you can use a listener inside the section with id content e.g:

```js
$('section#content').click(function(){
    $('section#navbar').css("display", "none") //or use a spacific class
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use try `node.contains()`[(doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) function inside click handler to check whether an event target is a descendant of a given node.

Like

```
if (!menu.contains(event.target)) {
  // close the menu
}
```