# navigation bar drawer menu doesn't close after clicking menu item

Tags: javascript, html, css

i built a navigation bar for my website.this code is brought from another site.  it's css here

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    background-color:#FFF
}

header {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#06C;
    z-index:1000;
}

.menu-bar {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:26px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px 12px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.menu-bar:hover {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius:50px;
}

#tag-menu {
    display:none;
}


#tag-menu:checked ~ div.drawer {
 animation: slide-in 0.5s ease;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.drawer {
    position:fixed;
    left:-280px;
    background-color:#06C;
    height:100%;
    z-index:100;
    width:200px;
    animation: slide-out 0.5s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.drawer ul li {
    list-style:none;
}

.drawer ul li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    border-top:1px solid #039;
}

.drawer ul li a:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.drawer ul li a i {
    width:50px;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:15px;
}


@keyframes slide-in {
 from {left: -280px;}
 to {left: 0;}
}

@keyframes slide-out {
 from {left: 0;}
 to {left: -280px;}
}
```

it's HTML here

```
<header>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tag-menu">
  <label class="fa fa-bars menu-bar" for="tag-menu"></label>


  <div class="drawer" id="drawer">
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-secret"></i>A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle "></i>D</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

My problem is that the navigation bar drawer menu doesn't close after clicking on menu item. i need to close the drawer after click any item on the drawer menu.  how to solve this problem. what are the scripts which i can use?. Your help is highly appreciated.Thanks

Demo is here:   http://androidcss.com/demos/css/css-drawer-menu/#

Comment: Hi Aksl, welcome to SO. You can add a class to the menu items and close the menu when a click on one of the items with javascript. I'll suggest you a solution in a minute in the answers.

Comment: ok,thanks. i am a newbie and your help is highly appriciated.

Comment: For open/close nav bar by clicking on menu item. It's already implemented, this is  the `@keyframes slide-in{}` and `@keyframes slide-out {}` CSS property

Comment: Since OP is starting out and already using a code from a tutorial that he probably does not understand half of it, I suggested a much simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the code a little bit because:

1. so you can have more flexibility later on when you want to add other things.
2. your nav menu will be closed from the start, not after 1 second like in the previous code used.
3. 58 lines of code instead of 125

It will also give you an introduction opportunity to jQuery.

Please see the comments that explain each line of code and write a comment if you don't understand something.

Codepen to play with: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/NWrGMWE

```js
$("#hamburger").click(function(){
    $("nav").toggleClass('open', 'close');
});

$("a").click(function(){
    $("nav").toggleClass('open', 'close');
});
```

```css
header, nav {
  background-color:#06C;font-family:'Open Sans';
}

header {
  width:100%;display:flex;align-items:center;
  height:80px;color:#FFF;justify-content:flex-start;
} /* we use flex display to position the hamburger icon on the side of the AndroiCSS h2 element */

#hamburger {
  cursor:pointer;
} /* add the small hand cursor pointer to indicate this element is clickable; it triggers the jQuery on click */

header * {
  margin:0 15px;
}

.fa-bars, header h2 {
  font-size:28px!important;
}

header h2 {
  font-weight:400!important;
}

nav {
  display:flex;flex-direction:column;width:0;align-items:center;
  transition:width 0.2s ease;
}

nav.open {
width:250px;
  }

nav.close {
  width:0;
}


nav * {
  color:#FFF!important;font-family:'Open Sans';font-size:20px!important;margin-right:15px;
}

nav a {
   text-decoration:none!important;
  border-top:0.5px solid gray;width:100%;text-align:center;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;height:55px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
} /* this changes the bg color on hover over the nav element */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>css drawer menu demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- this loads the font aswesome library for the hamburger icon (fa-bars) and the social icons; the class 'fa' calls the font awesome library and the fa-xxx class calls the specific icon needed-->
  <header>
    <i id="hamburger" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <h2>AndroidCSS</h2>
  </header>
  <nav>  
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>  <span>Facebook</span></a> <!-- nav menu no need for <ul> or <li> tags here -->
    <!-- the <a> tags are link tags and the <i> tags are used to call font awesome icons again -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Facebook</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Facebook</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Facebook</span></a>
    <a href="http://www.reddit.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Facebook</span></a>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Hi, LaurentC , i am really  greatful for your effort . You save me. i tried few days to solve this problem.but it was unsuccessful.your code works like a charm. really awesome. thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can mark the answer as Accepted if it helped :) cheers

Comment: okey, but it is defficult. because i dont have 15 reputations. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." so sad

Comment: It can be done like this : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work    thanks

Comment: Hi, LaurentC , your code is very useful and fine. no argument. but any chance to make drawer animation open to slide right, close to slide left. i mean android style. because i have planned to convert my website to an android app. your help is highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: hey @aksl sure you just have to update the jQuery function see the answer I updated it and the codepen too cheers

Comment: There is an issue !. When the navigation drawer  opens, other blocks of my website goes down. When drawer closes  web bloks come up to original places . Please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: OK. Can you open another quuestion and post relevant updated code?

Comment: yes. posted here.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382711/navigation-drawer-opens-by-pulling-down-other-web-blocks

Comment: Hello  LaurentC , help me please !

Comment: Additionally i need to close the navigation bar by anywhere of outside clicking. tried lot of ways but unsuccessful. my code was    <script>
$(document).click(function(event) {
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if(!$target.closest('nav').length &&
  $('nav').is(":visible")) {
    $('nav').hide();
  }
});
 </script>   any solution please!

Comment: will reply in the other question, this one is done.

Comment: i need to close the navigation bar by anywhere of outside clicking. But there are so many posts same to my question . I applied that js codes one by one.those all methods did not work. But i cant make posts same to that posts . Because it will be duplicate . Dear laurentC ,can i have a js code for this . Additionally  i want to get left align menu items . Need your  help .

Comment: Here is a most closer post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011182/how-to-close-site-navbar-when-onclick-outside but its also  unsuccessful for me.